# ¿Como obtener los elementos de un formulario de acuerdo a su tipo?

Tags: javascript, html5

Me explico tengo el problema que requiero poder obtener los elementos para luego insertar valores a estos de acuerdo a su tipo de `<input`, un `<textarea` o si es un `<select`. Un ejemplo de esto es el **autocompletador** de formularios que trae **Google Chrome** por defecto quiero lograr algo parecido pero desde **JS** para usar en una **extensión Firefox**.

Pero no encuentro la mejor forma ya que puedo usar

```
document.getElementsByTagName("input");
```

Y obtener todos **inputs** y luego dividir por su `type=""` pero no todos los formularios clasifican sus formularios por su tipo es decir el **input Name** lleva el `type="text"`  pero su `name=""` tiende a variar algunos solo llevan `name="name"` o `name="fistname"`, aunque sin importar esto **Google lo autocompleta** y esto quiero lograr.

Muchas gracias y espero su apoyo.

**Ejemplo de un caso:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Lo ideal es utilizar `querySelectorAll` para poder añadir el filtro por tipos  demás *(esto retornará una lista de Nodos o NodeList)* . Si utiliza `getElementsByTagName` solo podrá iterar el resultado e ir descartando elementos que no son del tipo deseado, pero este retornará todos los elementos con el nombre pasado por parámetro.

Si desea añadir más condiciones puede añadirla, por ejemplo obtener los `inputs` de tipo `date` con nombre `dt` sería.

```
document.querySelectorAll("input[type='date'][name='dt']");
```

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='text']");
const itemsDates = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='date'][name='dt']");
console.log(items);
console.log(itemsDates);
```

```html
<input type="text" >
<input type="button" value="">
<input type="date" name="dt">
<input type="date" name="">
<input type="date" name="dt">
<input type="date" name="">
<input type="date" name="dt">
<input type="text" name="dt">
```

Comment: Amigo entre 2 **Input** de tipo **text** como determino que uno sea el nombre y otro apellido o algo mas ?

Answer (score 1):

Con `querySelectorAll` puedes obtener todos los campos que necesites y agregarles un name para discriminar los campos.

```js
var fields = document.querySelectorAll(".input");

fields.forEach(field => console.log(field.name, field.value))
```

```html
<input class="input" type="text" name="first_name" value="hola">
<input class="input" type="text" name="last_name">
<input class="input" type="text" name="email">
```